# Qt deployment for windows copies incorrect dll for mingw

Tags: qt, dll, mingw, qt-creator

I set this build step to add deployment DLLs to my release folder:

```
Command: %{Qt:QT_INSTALL_BINS}/windeployqt.exe
Arguments: "%{CurrentProject:NativePath}\bin\server.exe" --no-translations
```

The correct QtXXXX.dll files are copied, but incorrect `libstdc++-6.dll` is added. The correct one is located at `QTDIR/bin/libstdc++-6.dll`, but instead, `windeployqt.exe` copies this DLL file from `C:\MinGW\bin`. If I try to run the application, I get this error:

[image: image description]

How can I tell `windeployqt.exe` to copy mingw files from `%{Qt:QT_INSTALL_BINS}` instead of my MinGW installation folder?

The version of Qt I am using is `Qt5.6.0-MinGW` with `mingw49_32`.

Comment: Have you tried writing in the command console: windeployqt.exe --help for additional options that can be used?

Comment: Yes, that's how I found out how to disable the translations. It does not say anything about overriding MinGW directory.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use the batch file that sets up the environment and comes with Qt then just make sure that the first compiler `g++.exe` found be `windeployqt.exe` is the one coming with Qt and **not** the one that got installed with MinGW. This way the correct library will get copied.

As an example from my own current installation:
Qt is installed to `C:\Qt\Qt5.8.0` and MinGW to `C:\MinGW`. Hence I add `C:\Qt\Qt5.8.0\Tools\mingw530_32\bin` **before** `C:\MinGW\bin` to my PATH. These two paths each contain a compiler `g++.exe`.